# "The system cannot find the file specified whenever I knit"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Whenever I knit to a PDF in RStudio, the error "The system cannot find the file specified."

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
##importing data
library(readr)
Quiz1data_2 <- read_csv("C:/Users/erinp/Downloads/Quiz1data-2.csv")
```

I have restarted RStudio multiple times and I have copied and pasted the exact link that my file is saved to and it's still not working.

What am I not seeing or what am I not thinking?

[image]

Comment: I figured it out. It's because I forgot to assign a value to an object so it wouldn't knit into a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions/questions:

Without knitting, when you run the line reading in the csv, does it work?

Also, are you sure that the error is referring to the data csv? Could it be referring to the (I'm assuming) markdown file you are writing your code in? Have you moved that file since you started working in it?

Are you able to knit other documents to pdf? You need MiKTeX on a windows machine. Does knitting to html work?

I've found R to be a little tricky reading in files. I usually use the base function like this:go to the environment tab>import dataset>from text(base)> (select the file you want, hit open)>(select settings so that the dataframe preview looks right>import. Code that does this will run in the console, and I copy it into my markdown file so that every time it knits, it replicates that successful process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because I forgot to assign a value to an object so it wouldn't knit into a PDF. I made a comment earlier, but it's small so I thought I would add this to the answer section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).